# How to use the difference between years as a variable in R?

Tags: r

Fieldwork was carried out summer 2013 and summer 2014. For my GLMM model I want to include year as a grouping variable. Each site has been attributed a date (as.Date), so if i use
 +(1|DATE) it would factor in all the days. Is there a way to quickly tell R to group by year?

Comment: Are you asking how to extract "year" from `Date` object?

Comment: For statistical (rather than computational) reasons I would recommend that you **not** use a two-level factor as a grouping variable for a random effect.  If you have two years and you want to distinguish between them in the model, it will probably work better to include them as a fixed effect instead (see http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq for more discussion).

Answer (score 0):

NDATE=factor(format(VPDATA$DATE, '%Y'))
boxplot(PLOTS~NDATE, data=VPDATA)

I found this bit of code and it worked (although it is as a factor). I'll follow up the link you sent B. Bolker, thanks for helping.